# Cannot install new version of Linux over Ubuntu

Tags: boot, elementary

I want to try new Linux distributions, and I can't get any to boot from USB or CD despite changing the boot order. 
It doesn't even detect that it's there at all. 
It works to boot onto on my desktop with Windows, but not my laptop with Ubuntu.
Does Ubuntu have some hidden setting or something?
Because the boot order already has the OS as the lowest one.

Comment: Ubuntu has no influence on the boot process. Even its default boot loader Grub2 is powerless, because you want to boot from a different medium entirely. How did you create your boot medium(s) and which boot image(s) did you try? Do you have UEFI or legacy BIOS?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no Ubuntu does not have any hidden settings which will not allow you to run another OS. More than likely your system is using some type of EFI, or your live disk does not detect the correct settings (either EFI/legacy).

You could need to make a live disk which has an EFI loader. Normally (with newer distros) when making a live disk with distributions, you will have both an EFI settings with loader, and normal/legacy loader on the same disk.

If this is not the case (you can examine disk contents for EFI), you may need to check for a live version which is compatible with EFI.

However if you are using BIOS, you may accidentally be loading the EFI settings, and would need to check to make sure you are loading the correct part of your disk.

Comment: Okay, so I tried to mount it directly within Ubuntu itself, and got this: Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sr0: Command-line `mount "/mnt/wwn-0x5001480000000000"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: block device /dev/sr0 is write-protected, mounting read-only
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error
       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail  or so"

Mean anything there?

Comment: @DakotaAnthoneyJacobson How are you mounting the CD/DVD? Are you doing it from a live environment?

Comment: No, I cannot access the live environment period. It won't boot on startup like it should. I tried to boot it from Ubuntu, but it wouldn't allow it.

Comment: @DakotaAnthoneyJacobson I am trying to figure out what command you used to mount it, and where you mounted the CD/DVD. Mounting it directly from within Ubuntu (unless you are doing like a chroot shell) isn't really the method you would use, it would be at startup, which you say does not work. Do you have BIOS, or EFI?

Comment: I do not know what either of those are, so no. And since it wouldn't boot on startup of the computer, I tried to force it when the computer loaded Ubuntu.

Comment: UEFI/EFI and BIOS are what you would be using to set your boot orders. UEFI is newer and has it's own issues, BIOS is older and has it's own issues. Depending on which one you have (not OS dependent, rather motherboard/computer dependent) it will determine whether or not certain livedisks will work. They [BIOS/UEFI] don't work together well, which is why most livedisks for distros will include both .efi files, as well a `/boot` folder. Also the disk will need to be flagged as bootable.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem.

The way I resolved it was to create about 5 or 6 small partitions in fat16 and copy lots of text files to them.  Then I deleted them and created a couple of NTFS partitions where they were and did similar.
Finally, I deleted those partitions, rebooted and installed my desired ubuntu partitions and installed ubuntu.

It wasn't a different linux, but it was the same problem.  I couldn't use the desired partition routine because ubuntu wouldn't load.

The drive developed the problem after installing Ubuntu 14.04 with LTS option.

It's a pain, but it worked for me.
I hope this helps